# Prove that if the sum of each row of $A$ equals $s$, then $s$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix.

$i)$Prove that if the sum of each row of $A$ equals $s$, then $s$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

$ii)$Prove that if the sum of each column of $A$ equals $s$, then $s$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

I think that being an eigenvalue of $A$ implies that $sv=Av$ for some vector $v$. Furthermore, I know that $[a_i] = s$ if we let $a_i$ denote the i-th row of $A$. However, I do not seem to be able to find a link between these two facts. Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: The easiest way to start is to find the eigenvector. Think of a vector $x$ such that the $i$-th entry of $Ax$ is the $i$-th row sum of $A$.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

HINT: Calculate $Av$ when $v=(1,1,\ldots ,1,1)^t$, what can you say?

Comment: That every element in $Av$ is equal to $s$ I think? So that would indeed mean that $s$ is an eigenvalue in this case. However, how does this proof the general case?

Comment: @mause: What do you mean by the general case ? The HINT says that $v$ is an eigen vector with corresponding eigen value $s$, thats what you wanted to show.

Comment: Yes, but what I mean is, don't I have to show that this holds for arbitraty $v$? Because your hint only shows that this is true if you choose this particular $v$.

Comment: @mause:You don't have to show for arbitrary $v$. The definition of eigen value of a matrix is: $\lambda$ is an eigen value of $A$ if $\textit{there exists}$ a vector $v$ such that $v\ne 0$ and $Av=\lambda v$.

Comment: @mause If $Av=sv$ for any *arbitrary* $v$, then $A=sI$. You don't think that $sI$ is the *only* matrix whose row sums are equal to $s$, do you?

Comment: @pritam I see your point now :). Thank you for your help :).

Comment: @user1551 I see now that you're right indeed. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

There is a simple simple proof beind this,

Let A = $
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a & b & c \\
        d & e & f \\
        g & h & i \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$ such that (a+b+c) = (d+e+f) = (g+h+i) = s (say).

Now AX = λX , X ≠ 0.
So for calculating its eigenvalue simply observe the det (A-λI):

det(A-λI) = $
        \begin{vmatrix}
        a - λ & b & c \\
        d & e - λ & f \\
        g & h & i- λ \\
        \end{vmatrix}
$ = 0

Thus,
$
        \begin{vmatrix}
        a + b +c - λ & b & c \\
        d + e + f  - λ  & e - λ & f \\
        g+h+i - λ & h & i- λ \\
        \end{vmatrix}
$ = 0

So,
 $
        \begin{vmatrix}
        s - λ & b & c \\
        s  - λ  & e - λ & f \\
       s- λ & h & i- λ \\
        \end{vmatrix}
$ = 0

And hence,

$
        \begin{vmatrix}
        s - λ
        \end{vmatrix}*\begin{vmatrix}1 & b & c \\1 & e - λ & f \\1 & h & i- λ \\
        \end{vmatrix}
$ = 0.

Hence, we conclude that s is an eigenvalue of A. Similarly, we prove when sum of each column is constant all over the matrix.

Comment: Sorry for bringing this question back, but what operation did you perform to get from step 1 to 2?

Comment: I have used C1 = C1 + C2 + C3.

Comment: I still don't get it, why C1 = C1 + C2 + C3 should be equal. Is there some theorem I don't know that says this should be true