# Finding spectral radius of matrix without computing characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, spectral-radius

Let

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}3&1&1\\1&2&1\\0&1&2\end{pmatrix}.$$

I am asked to find its spectral radius, i.e., $$\rho(A) = \max \left\{ |\lambda| : \lambda \text{ eigenvalue of }A \right\}$$ without using the characteristic polynomial. I have tried Gershgorin circles, bounding by norms ($\rho(A)=\inf_{\|\cdot\|}{\| A \|}$), etc. I only got $\rho(A)\leq4$ with these methods. Any ideas?

(Practice exam of Numerical-Methods for Algebra, 2nd Grade in Mathematics).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35445/estimating-the-spectral-radius-of-a-matrix-noniteratively

Comment: To garantee the power iteration converges, how do you prove that $A$ has an eigenvalue that is strictly greater in magnitude than its other eigenvalues?

Comment: Perron-Frobenius?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that theorem. Now, by the power iteration, starting with the normalized vector $1/\sqrt{3}(1,1,1)$, I get 4 as the first approximation to $\rho(A)$, which is indeed the exact value. But how can I prove the power iteration converges to 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, I post it in order to mark the question as answered.

As shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347408/prove-that-if-the-sum-of-each-row-of-a-equals-s-then-s-is-an-eigenvalue-o), since $\sum_{i=1}^3a_{ij}=4$ for $j=1,2,3$, we have that 4 is eigenvalue of $A$. Therefore,
$$\rho(A)\geq4$$
and we conclude $\rho(A)=4$.

Comment: Incomplete.  Please mention how you obtained the $\leq 4$ part.

Comment: Comments are ephemeral. They can be deleted easily.